# Monodevelop installation on Ubuntu 22.04

Tags: monodevelop

When I try to install Monodevelop on Ubuntu 22.04 I get GPG errors.

I followed https://www.monodevelop.com/download/#fndtn-download-lin-ubuntu, and https://ubunlog.com/en/monodevelop-ide-installation-via-ppa/ to install Monodevelop. The `sudo apt-key ...` command fails and reports to be deprecated. With missing keys, `sudo apt update` fails to reach mono repository, and I cannot install Monodevelop.

On update I get the following output:

```
Err:1 https://download.mono-project.com/repo/ubuntu vs-bionic InRelease
  The following signatures couldn't be verified because the public key is not available: NO_PUBKEY A6A19B38D3D831EF
Reading package lists... Done
W: GPG error: https://download.mono-project.com/repo/ubuntu vs-bionic InRelease: The following signatures couldn't be verified because the public key is not available: NO_PUBKEY A6A19B38D3D831EF
E: The repository 'https://download.mono-project.com/repo/ubuntu vs-bionic InRelease' is not signed.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
```

I have also tried do add keys with gpg. I imported some keys, but apt still reports missing keys. I have tried:

```
curl -sSL "https://keyserver.ubuntu.com/pks/lookup?op=get&search=0x3FA7E0328081BFF6A14DA29AA6A19B38D3D831EF" | gpg --import
curl -sSL "https://keyserver.ubuntu.com/pks/lookup?op=get&search=0xA6A19B38D3D831EF" | gpg --import
curl -sSL https://download.mono-project.com/repo/xamarin.gpg | gpg --import
sudo gpg --keyserver download.mono-project.com --recv-key 3FA7E0328081BFF6A14DA29AA6A19B38D3D831EF
```

Does anybody have an idea how to install Monodevelop on Ubuntu 22.04? Snap would also be an option, but I cannot find it in snap store.